# Are there any definitions of (geometric) complexity of shapes that do not rely upon quantity of information?

Tags: geometry, entropy, geometric-complexity

I am interested in finding a measure for the complexity of geometric objects. I am focused primarily on closed figures composed of lines, curves and surfaces. Therefore, any measure of the complexity must relate to these components and their interrelations.

I intuit that, for example:

- The least complex object would be a point. A circle has the least complexity of the 2D shapes.
- Pentagons have more complexity than triangles. Triangles have more complexity than circles.
- It is likely that fractal curves (e.g. the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set)), are the greatest-complexity 2D shapes.
- Cubes have greater complexity than squares.
- Otherwise comparing 3D shapes and 2D shapes is challenging, but should be possible.
- The [great stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_stellated_dodecahedron) has greater complexity than the regular dodecahedron (and of course the cube).
- Naturally, the shape of St. Paul's Cathedral in London has far more complexity than a simple polyhedron.
- It is likely that a torus has more complexity than a sphere.

I would like to identify a measure to quantify this topological / geometric complexity, which:

1. Produces a rank ordering of complexity for geometric objects which corresponds to intuition
2. Allows the comparison of the 'relative
   complexity' between objects, which also corresponds to intuition
3. Is rotationally and translationally
   invariant
4. Does not incorporate concepts of 'order' such as entropy or symmetry

A particularly intelligent approach I have found is described in the paper [Shape complexity based on mutual information](https://dugi-doc.udg.edu/bitstream/handle/10256/3066/192.pdf?sequence=1) by Rigau et al. The authors propose a technique to use continuous mutual information to measure the complexity of 2D and 3D shapes, including compound polyhedra and [Von Koch fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake). However, the approach conflate orderliness and complexity, breaching rule (4) above. I believe that the otherwise-promising measures of [Topological entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy) / [Haussdorf Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) suffer from the same issue.

My suspicion is that one can define a far-simpler, and more general, complexity measure using something like (vaguely) 'the density of discontinuities' or the 'average differentiability'. My question is, does such a definition exist already? Do similar attempts exist in the literature which I may have missed?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous. From the first paragraph, it seems that you are looking for notion of complexity restricted to polyhedra. However, you specify no desired properties of complexity. Then suddenly, you are talking about fractals and entropy (of what?). You should spend more time thinking about what is it that you are actually aiming for. In the present form your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Moise said just what I wanted to say. What intuition are you trying to express? Just some examples might help here. Does a sphere have more, less, or  the same topological complexity than a cube?

Comment: I feel rule (4) is the most interesting part of your question: we are used to identify complexity of something with the amount of information needed to define it, you precisely reject that. Unfortunately, when you say "(a complexity) which corresponds to intuition", we do not share the same intuition about complexity, as mine is heavily linked to quantity of information. Perhaps your question could be accepted if it was limited to "Are there any definitions of (geometric) complexity in the literature, that do not rely upon quantity of information ?".

Comment: This is still very unclear. One thing is clear however: your notion cannot be topological since it is not a homeomorphism invariant. Here is a suggestion: Start by working out details for a very restricted class, for instance, simple closed polygonal curves (not necessarily convex) and see what your intuition tells you.

Comment: Moishe, I agree with you regarding topological complexity; that was misleading - the context is shapes and their complexity, not spaces. @Jean-Armand, thank you for helping to clarify the point; I am interested in a measure of complexity which does not rely on order (i.e. symmetry etc.). The reasons for this are too many to expound in comments, but simply I now believe that complexity and order exist independently - and that their combination (via shorter-alphabet source codings)  provides the observable information. In some sense, complexity is what is left after you remove the redundancy.